# Difference between renewing commands before and after \begin{document}

Tags: best-practices, preamble

I was wondering what could be reasons for differences when I redefine control sequences in the preamble or after `\begin{document}`?

For example, this code typesets **abcd** when compiled by any of `pdflatex`, `htlatex`, and `mk4ht oolatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\b{b}
a\b cd
\end{document}
```

But if `\renewcommand\b{b}` is moved to the preamble, `pdflatex` and `htlatex` will still output **abcd**, while `mk4ht oolatex` will now output **ac̱d**.  That is, instead of `b`, `\b` will expand to the standard sub-macron (`0x331`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\b{b}
\begin{document}
a\b cd
\end{document}
```

I assume the missing `b` in these examples is not due to a bug in `mk4ht oolatex`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some reasons or considerations:

- From a programming point of view, structure promotes good practice. As such, document *style/structure* is typically performed within the document preamble (between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`), while document *content* follows within the `document` environment.
- Some commands are defined to be used *only* within the preamble. With the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) this is identified via `\@onlypreamble`. These include, amongst a host of others, `\usepackage`.
- Depending on your document structure, you may be inclined to construct your layout in a compartmentalized fashion. To that end, you insert both structural/stylistic and content matter inside a single file which you include using `\input` somewhere within your document. This is fine as long as the commands used are not designated as `\@onlypreamble`.
- Some package perform redefinitions `\AtBeginDocument`. So, performing a usual `\renewcommand` may not have the expected effect, unless you place it inside an `\AtBeginDocument`-delayed clause yourself.

So, why not? It depends on the use case, but as long as there is consistency (via structure or compartmentalization alone), there is no need to stick to this rule.

Comment: there's also the case where the action of a command needs to change *within* the document (or within a portion of the document).  in such a case, it would be necessary to make the change after the preamble, and even `\begin{document}`, is long gone.