# Use letters as item labels by default in enumerate and with Beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I know how to use letters for individual lists:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Self-test 2.4:}
What are the following limits?

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But how can I tell Beamer that I want to use letters by default?  Note that solutions for ordinary enumerations likely won't work since Beamer has its own implementation of lists.

Comment: Please provide us a executable MWE.

Comment: @MishraS , done.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2292 and associated links in the question and answers can probably help

Comment: @jchd thanks, but Beamer has its own implementation of lists, so neither of these solutions work.

Comment: @tmalsburg. You have to specify the same (letter type) in the enumerate environment. I hope there is no other way, as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517919/use-letters-as-item-labels-by-default-in-enumerate-and-with-beamer?answertab=votes#comment1309801_517919) a bit more precise, the following works for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\begin{frame}{Self-test 2.4:}
What are the following limits?
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the `\renewcommand` is placed **after** `\begin{document}`. I guess that beginning the document has the effect of overwriting `\theenumi`, but I don't exactly understand how/why. (related? [Difference between renewing commands before and after \begin{document}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161009/difference-between-renewing-commands-before-and-after-begindocument))

Comment: Oh, that does in fact work. And yes, I had tried it with the renewcommand in the header.  Wasn't aware that this makes a difference.  Thank you!

Comment: I found the beamer way of doing this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518066/34277

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to [jchd's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517973/34277), but perhaps slightly more idiomatic, is to include the following in the header:

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\alph{enumi})}
```

The complete example is then:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\alph{enumi})}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Self-test 2.4:}
What are the following limits?

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```